# Problem with overlay on picture in css (html)

Tags: html, css

I have problem with adding overlay on image in my html project. It should looks like overlay coming from bottom of image when it's hovered, but instead it's only like link on all the image. Here is code from html and css:

```css
.tile5 {
  width: 480px;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 304px;
  float: left;
}

.overlay {
  position: relative;
  width: 480px;
  height: 304px;
}

.overlay .link {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #111;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.overlay:hover .link {
  opacity: 0, 8;
}
```

```html
<div class="square">
  <div class="tile5">
    <div class="overlay">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="grafika/obraz.jpg" style="width: 480px; height: 304px; border-radius: 10px;" />
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="link">tekkst teskttekkst teskttekkst teskttekkst teskttekkst teskt</a>
    </div>
    ...other element in div 'square'
  </div>
```

I hope someone will help;)

Comment: Is `opacity: 0, 8;` a typo? Did you mean `opacity: 0.8` ? Your anchor will fade a little if you correct that when hovered

Comment: Note: the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: yeah i mean 0.8, my fault @Huangism.

Comment: @Rob thanks rob, didn't saw that

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```css
.tile5 {
  width: 480px;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 304px;
  float: left;
  position:relative;
}

.overlay {
  position: relative;
  width: 480px;
  height: 304px;
}

.overlay .link {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  left: 0px;
  top: 40%;
  opacity:0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  z-index:99999;
  color:white;
  padding:10px 20px;
  text-decoration:none;
}

.overlay:hover .link {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<div class="square">
  <div class="tile5">
    <div class="overlay">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/206959/pexels-photo-206959.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" style="width: 480px; height: 304px; border-radius: 10px;" />
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="link">tekkst teskttekkst teskttekkst teskttekkst teskttekkst teskt</a>
    </div>
    ...other element in div 'square'
  </div>
```

Comment: im not really shure how to us it in ma special layout ( https://ibb.co/HdC2qJ2 ), but i see on snippet it works;)

Comment: I edited the code so that it is using your code as a base.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your HTML structure a bit off. The tag with class overlay.

Here's how I would go about it. I think you are trying to have an image caption visible on hover

**HTML**

```
 <div class="square">
        <a href="#"> 
          <img src="grafika/obraz.jpg" style="width: 480px; height: 304px; border-radius: 10px;"/>
          <span>Caption Here</span>
        </a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.square{
    position: relative;
    width: 480px;
    height: 304px;
    float: left;
}
.square a span{
  background:#efebeb;
  max-width: 480px;
  width:100%;
  color:#000;
  padding:20px 0px;
   position: absolute;
   left:0;
   bottom:0;
   opacity: 0;
   transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
   text-align:center;
}
.square a:hover span{
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It's working really good. Can you tell me what do you think about this operation, but I want to activate span when i hover different object (tile2,tile2 and tile3). Here is my layout:  ibb.co/HdC2qJ2